# How to mirror traffic to Suricata container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, suricata

My goal is to sniff all traffic of the"attacker" container with suricata so all its suspicious traffic makes an alert jump. So my planning was to have something like this:

[image: image.png]

So that both containers could have internet acces through the host with my_network and another network (attacknet) in which I would mirror the traffic of attacker in my_network so that suricata could listen it. In order to mirror the traffic I am using Daemonlogger with `daemonlogger -i eth1 -o eth0`.
Trying to achieve thsi I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

    suricata:
      container_name: suricata
      build: ./suricata
      depends_on:
        - syslog
      networks:
        my_network:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
        attacknet:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.233.10
    attacker:
      container_name: attacker
      build: ./attacker
      networks:
        my_network:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11
        attacknet:
          ipv4_address: 172.16.233.11
          
networks:
  my_network:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
  attacknet:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.233.0/24
```

But it is not working, suricata isn't getting the traffic. What am I doing wrong? Or maybe you have another method to achieve my final goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use [`iptables` and `tee`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) on the Docker host to mirror the traffic to another ([bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/)) interface, which could be the one used by your [Suricata](https://suricata.io/) container.

You would:

1. Create a bridge, e.g., `br0`, in the Docker host and assign it an IP address. (you may need to install the `bridge-utils` package first)

   ```
   sudo brctl addbr br0  # create a new bridge named br0
   sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev br0  # assign the IP address 192.168.1.1 with a netmask of 255.255.255.0 to br0
   ```
2. Assign the "`attacker`" and "`suricata`" containers to the same Docker network, which is associated with br0.
   (see `docker-compose.yml` below)
3. Use `iptables` and `tee` to duplicate the traffic:

   ```
   iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i br0 ! -s <suricata IP> -j TEE --gateway <suricata IP>
   ```
4. Setup Suricata to listen on its network interface.
   Check first the name of the interface name with `docker exec -it suricata bash -c "ip addr"`: Look for the interface that has an IP address on the same network as your "attacker" container.
   Then edit `/etc/suricata/suricata.yaml`, section `af-packet:`, put `- interface: eth1`. Once edited: `service suricata restart`.

Here is an updated `docker-compose.yml` based on your file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  suricata:
    container_name: suricata
    build: ./suricata
    networks:
      attacknet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
  attacker:
    container_name: attacker
    build: ./attacker
    networks:
      attacknet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11

networks:
  attacknet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

In that configuration, Suricata and attacker are on the same Docker network. You can set up `iptables` to mirror the traffic from attacker to Suricata as mentioned above.

This remains a high-level sketch, and it might need adjustments based on your particular setup.
And the `iptables` rule mentioned above is just a simplistic example, to be adjusted it based on the traffic flow you are interested in (inbound, outbound, etc.), making sure to not create a traffic loop.

If you are trying to run this setup on a cloud platform, the network interface mirroring option might not be available due to the limitations imposed by the cloud provider's network virtualization. You might want to consider running this setup on a bare-metal or self-managed virtualized environment, at least for testing it out.

---

An alternative to this would be to use a Network Function Virtualization platform, such as TNSR or pfSense, which can mirror packets from one interface to another.

---

> When you say "Assign the "attacker" and "suricata" containers to the same Docker network, which is associated with br0.", how do you actually define this in the docker-compose file?
> I don't see the relation in the file not the Ips nor any mentioning of the interface br0.

In Docker, when you [define a network in a `docker-compose.yml` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and assign that network to a service, Docker will automatically create a [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/) for that network and connect the service's container to it. The bridge will be automatically assigned a name by Docker and not explicitly mentioned in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, you have defined a network named `attacknet` and assigned it to your `suricata` and `attacker` services:

```yaml
services:
  suricata:
    container_name: suricata
    build: ./suricata
    networks:
      attacknet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10
  attacker:
    container_name: attacker
    build: ./attacker
    networks:
      attacknet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.11

networks:
  attacknet:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
```

When you start these services with `docker-compose up`, Docker will create a new bridge for the `attacknet` network and assign the `suricata` and `attacker` containers to it. The actual name of the bridge (which might be something like `br-<random ID>`) is not specified in your `docker-compose.yml` file, but you can find it by running the [command `docker network inspect attacknet`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/).

So when I referred to `br0`, it was a hypothetical example. In the context of your setup, you can replace `br0` with the actual bridge interface Docker has created for your `attacknet` network.

The IPv4 addresses you are assigning to your services (`172.16.238.10` and `172.16.238.11`) are the addresses these services will have within the `attacknet` network. The subnet for the `attacknet` network (`172.16.238.0/24`) is also defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: Hello, when you say "Assign the "attacker" and "suricata" containers to the same Docker network, which is associated with br0.", how do you actually define this in the docker-compose file? I dont see the relation in the file not the Ips nor any mentioning of the interface br0.